# Fetch the data from database using the same column of same table using hash map

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp, hashmap

I want to fetch the data from database using hashmap.

Example- 
Table Name Menu

```
Restaurant_ID Item_Name Price Category
    1101        Burger    59    A
    1101        pizza     101   A
    1101        colddrink  40   B
    1101        bread      30   B
```

Output must be like this

Category A

```
Item_name      Price
Burger          59
Pizza           101
```

Category B

```
Item_name      Price
colddrink       40
bread           30
```

I want to fetch the data like this from table MENU to my jsp page.

Please help me .
i have tried so many this but i did'nt get the output as i need.

Comment: Please share what you already tried

Comment: You have given 2 outputs here. You want both of them to come from same query or multiple queries will also be acceptable to you?

Comment: multiple query is acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `ArrayList` here but it will give the same output as you want from your code:

Step 1: Get all the categories from `Table_Name_Menu` table into an `ArrayList`

```
public static ArrayList<Characters> getCategories(Connection con) throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    String query =
        "select distinct(Category) from Table_Name_Menu order by Category ASC";

    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    ArrayList<Character> categories = new ArrayList<Character>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        char category = rs.getString("Category").charAt(0);
        categories.add(category);
    }
    //This way, all the categories will come in categories Arraylist

    stmt.close();
    return categories;
}
```

*Note: This is an Uncompiled code. Please put Try and Catch blocks accordingly.*

Step 2: Iterate through your `categories` ArrayList and for each of these categories, prepare a new query that will fetch all the contents corresponding to that particular `Category`

```
for(Iterator<Character> i = category.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Statement stmt = null;
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    char newCategory = i.next();
    String query2 = "select Item_name, Price from Table_Name_Menu where Category = \"" +  newCategory + "\"";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query2);

    //This prints the contents of the new Category
    System.out.println("Category : " + newCategory):
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1)); //Item Name
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2)); //Item Price
    }
    stmt.close();

    System.out.println("\n\n"); //Gap Between categories
}
```

This way you'll get all the contents corresponding to a particular category.

Comment: If this is not what you want then please clarify your need, I'll modify the answer accordingly.